# how to implenting the Azure Organization AD Authentication in MRBS a web application based on PHP?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm currently implementing Azure AD authentication for user login in a Meeting Room Booking System (MRBS) https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code/tree/main. I've followed the provided documentation and integrated the authentication logic https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code/blob/main/AUTHENTICATION#L969 into my codebase. However, I'm encountering some errors and difficulties in debugging the process and code.

I've configured the necessary parameters in config.inc.php, including the Azure AD client ID, client secret, redirect URI, and tenant ID. However, when I try to authenticate using Azure AD, I'm not redirected to the Azure AD sign-in page as expected.

I suspect there might be errors in the authentication logic or issues with handling the callback after authentication. Additionally, I'm not sure how to properly handle errors and debug the process.

Can someone help me understand what might be going wrong with the authentication flow in this code? How can I properly handle errors and debug the Azure AD authentication process in PHP?

My purpose is that I want to enable the login process in the MRBS through email id (user can login with their organization email id (microsoft))

I'm using the AuthAzuread class provided by the MRBS project, which handles the authentication flow with Azure AD.

```
<?php
namespace MRBS\Auth;

/*
 * Authentication scheme that uses Azure AD for user authentication.
 * Main file: https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code/tree/main
 *
 * For Authentication documentation: https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code/blob/main/AUTHENTICATION
 *
 * To use this authentication scheme, set the following in config.inc.php:
 *
 * $auth["type"] = "azuread";
 * $auth["azuread_client_id"] = "YOUR_AZUREAD_CLIENT_ID";
 * $auth["azuread_client_secret"] = "YOUR_AZUREAD_CLIENT_SECRET";
 * $auth["azuread_redirect_uri"] = "https://your-mrbs-url.com/login.php"; // Redirect URI configured in Azure AD
 * $auth["azuread_tenant_id"] = "YOUR_AZUREAD_TENANT_ID";
 *
 */

use MRBS\User;

class AuthAzuread extends Auth
{
    private $auth;

    public function __construct($auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        // Check if azuread_tenant_id, azuread_client_id, and azuread_client_secret are provided
        if (!isset($this->auth['azuread_tenant_id'])) {
            throw new \Exception("Azure AD Tenant ID is missing.");
        }
        if (!isset($this->auth['azuread_client_id'])) {
            throw new \Exception("Azure AD Client ID is missing.");
        }
        if (!isset($this->auth['azuread_client_secret'])) {
            throw new \Exception("Azure AD Client Secret is missing.");
        }
    }

    public function validateUser(?string $user, ?string $pass)
    {
        // Encode the redirect URI
        $redirectUri = urlencode($this->auth["azuread_redirect_uri"]);

        // Redirect users to Azure AD sign-in page
        $azureADSignInUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$this->auth['azuread_tenant_id']}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?" . http_build_query([
            "client_id" => $this->auth["azuread_client_id"],
            "response_type" => "code",
            "redirect_uri" => $redirectUri, // Include the encoded redirect URI
            "scope" => "openid profile email",
        ]);

        header("Location: $azureADSignInUrl");
        exit;
    }

    public function handleCallback()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
            $authorizationCode = $_GET['code'];

            // Exchange authorization code for access token
            $tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{$this->auth['azuread_tenant_id']}/oauth2/v2.0/token";
            $tokenParams = [
                "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                "client_id" => $this->auth["azuread_client_id"],
                "client_secret" => $this->auth["azuread_client_secret"],
                "scope" => "openid profile email",
                "redirect_uri" => $this->auth["azuread_redirect_uri"],
                "code" => $authorizationCode,
            ];

            $tokenData = $this->getToken($tokenEndpoint, $tokenParams);

            if (isset($tokenData['access_token'])) {
                $accessToken = $tokenData['access_token'];
                $userInfo = $this->getUserInfo($accessToken);

                if ($userInfo) {
                    return new User($userInfo['email'], $userInfo['name']);
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception('Failed to retrieve user information from Microsoft Graph API');
                }
            } elseif (isset($tokenData['error'])) {
                // Token request failed with error response
                $error = $tokenData['error'];
                $errorDescription = isset($tokenData['error_description']) ? $tokenData['error_description'] : '';

                throw new \Exception("Token request failed with error: $error. Description: $errorDescription");
            } else {
                throw new \Exception('Failed to obtain access token from Azure AD');
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private function getToken($tokenEndpoint, $tokenParams)
    {
        // Send POST request to token endpoint with client secret
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $tokenEndpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($tokenParams));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    private function getUserInfo($accessToken)
    {
        // Make a request to Microsoft Graph API using the access token
        $graphApiEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me';
        $headers = [
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
            'Accept: application/json'
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $graphApiEndpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $userInfo = json_decode($response, true);

        // Check if user info retrieval was successful
        if (isset($userInfo['mail']) && isset($userInfo['displayName'])) {
            return [
                'email' => $userInfo['mail'],
                'name' => $userInfo['displayName']
            ];
        } else {
            // User info retrieval failed
            throw new \Exception('Failed to retrieve user information from Microsoft Graph API');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want users from any tenant to authenticate?

Comment: yes, I have these things :
Application (client) ID
Directory (tenant) ID
Secret Value

Comment: Create the application by selecting option as Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant) and use sign in URL as https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: Or for an existing application go to Mainfest and update "signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

Comment: we are using this application :
https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code/tree/main

here is the documentation to create a new authentication for the user:
https://github.com/meeting-room-booking-system/mrbs-code/blob/main/AUTHENTICATION#L969

Comment: In the Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> App registrations is your application present?

Comment: yes, I did the application register there, then I got these things from there:
Application (client) ID, 
Directory (tenant) ID, and 
Secret Value

i got and error after creating a custom code to implement the azure active directory:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256886/discussion-between-rukmini-and-abid-fakhrealam).